# Is it safe to have your API URL and key exposed?

Tags: api

I'm building a vue js app that I'm looking to deploy soon, for now I use axios and I have a .NET Web API and a database from which I fetch my data. To achieve that I make requests to my API URL with the relevant paths of course which looks like this:

> https://path-xyz.xyz/path/to/something

The question that I'm having is the following: Is it safe to have this exposed. Basically everyone can see it by navigating to the Network tab on the inspect section of the browser. Would this in any way make my API more likely to fail or be attacked? If yes then what can I do to hide it or make it more secure?

Comment: Define "secure" in this case.  Since the client-side application is accessing this API then presumably the *user* has access to this API, right?  In that case what difference does it make if the user accesses it manually or via the application code?

Comment: Hello David, thank you for the comment. Since I'm really new to programming I'm unsure about many things and this is one of it. I have build the API myself and have it deployed too, I'm just unsure if it is safe to have it exposed to everyone who wants to see it. Is the API key or path something that I should look to hide or is this not necessary? Is having the API exposed making my application more vulnerable to attacks?

Comment: Well, if you want clients to be able to use your API then those clients would need to know the URL for that API.  I don't know what "API key" you're referring to, but presumably it's some token you provide to the user to access your API, no?  If that's the case then surely the client would also need to know their API key in order to use the API.  You're essentially asking if it's safe to allow users to access an API that you want them to access.  The user either has access or they don't, it can't be both.  What exactly are you looking to *prevent* in this case?

Comment: By API key I mean the path to which I make make calls for example if I want to login I would use https://api/Login, in this case the /Login. I'm sorry if thats not the correct way to call it, my apologies. I want my frontend application to make calls to my API. I'm essentially asking if it is safe for my API (the endpoints to which I make requests -https://api/Login ; https://api/Register ; https://api/Cars) to be exposed to anyone who wants to use my website.

Comment: As far as terminology goes, that's not an "API key".  That's just the URL (or path, or URI, etc.) of the resource (or endpoint).  And it really sounds like you're still trying to ask if it's okay to let clients know about an API that you want clients to know about.  If the client needs to access these API endpoints in order for the application to function then the client needs to access these API endpoints.  Whether or not it's *safe* entirely depends on the code you write and what these endpoints do.  But the client certainly needs to *know about them* in order to use them.

Comment: Thank you for the correction David, also thank you for the time you took to reply and dive into my problem. I understand my application needs the API URL to be able to make the calls and function properly. I dont want to hide it from my application but to not show it to random users online. Right now anyone can just go to the application url and in the network tab of the browser devtools they can see the API URLs I use to make calls and access data from my database. I dont know whether or not the API URLs is information I somehow hide from people from the internet or not.

Comment: I'm really sorry if what im asking is not really relevant and thank you once again for the patience and time! @David

Comment: You can't both *show* the URLs to the client *and hide* the URLs from the client at the same time.  If the client needs to access these endpoints then the client needs to *know about* these endpoints.  As an analogy, imagine asking someone to send you a package in the mail but not allowing them to know your address.  How do you expect them to send the package?  As far as "anybody can access them" is concerned... Yes, anybody can *send a request* to them.  What you *do* with that request is up to you.  If only certain users should access this data then you want authentication/authorization.

Comment: @David, I guess I'm worrying about something I shouldn't. Thank you very much for your time and help. Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

If the web application needs to access an API in order to perform operations that the application is expected to perform - then whatever the web application can see, the user can see - as the users have full access to the programs running on their devices.

I think a question that wasn't addressed in the discussion and warrants addressing is the difference between API structure and the API credentials when looking at the security of a publicly accessible (i.e. not blocked by a firewall or such) API: you have to accept that any anonymous user would be able to read the source code of your web application and deduce the full structure of your API, and that cannot be your system's security.

On the other hand, you should make sure that the authorization tokens that allow **the use** of the API are only provisioned after a secure authentication process and the tokens are not embedded into the readable source code of the web application, and then your system's security isn't dependent on the structure of the API but on the secrecy of the authorization tokens.